# How to handle ERP base application in Angular

Tags: javascript, .net, angular, .net-core, angular8

I have Angular app currently consist of one project and multiples modules regarding that project.But my question is when ERP base application is developed in Angular ( as back end we are using .Net Core) then how to manage each ERP module because each module(Project) consist of angular modules so that at run main.js size remain small. From server side we can manage it as micro-services but how to handle them in front end side so that we easily manage main.js ( to remain safe from increasing main.js size )

**Any help will be very much appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got the answer for this question . The answer is I will create multiple modules and each module has its own models and services and I load each module on demand. That is the brief explanation of this question that I learn during working on different Angular projects